# WPF windows can't find icon path

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have a project with many sub projects A,B,C...
Sub project A is dependent on B,C which they don't reference project A in anyway.

I have wpf windows in B and C that uses icons. All icons are resources is a sub folder in Project A. The wpf designer for windows in B and C can't find the path for the images. However at run time the images appear as expected. The only way I was able to get rid of the error is by creating a sub folder and copy the images from project A over to the sub projects B and C. This is a work around.

How can I solve this issue ?

The image path for the controls "/myIcons/tree.ico" in controls in project B.

I have tried using the pack URI syntax with no luck.

Comment: For a simple solution,what i would do is create a seperate project, call it "Resources" and dump any media or files that can be used globally. There are probably some other ways, but you cant really reference Project A in the others as that creates a circular reference.

Comment: @GingerNinja I inherited the structure of the project this way. It is too late to change it at this stage. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: As far as i have experienced, I dont know a way to reference a parent project without a circular reference. I feel there is a problem with the design if that is what you need. Because you indicated you cant redesign, it seems like you can only do a hacked solution anyways. I would just copy in any resources to the project that needs them. so if you have Image1 that you want to use in multiple projects. I would copy Image1 into Project A and Project B.

Comment: @GingerNinja Why the windows in sub project B uses the icons from project A even though the resource is defined in B ? I have run a test and I confirmed that the image from project A is used. If I remove the resource from project A, I get a run time error.

Comment: i cant really answer that without seeing all the information at Runtime and the project layout.